# Confusion about the Frobenius Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I am trying to solve the problem using the Frobenius method around x=0  $$3x^2y''-xy'+y=0$$
$$F(r)=r(r-1)+p_0r+q_0$$
since $$p(x)=-1/3$$ $$q(x)=1/3$$
then
$$F(r)=r^2-4/3r-1/3=0$$
$$r=2/3±\sqrt{7}/3$$
the difference between r1 and r2 is a non integer so we use the following method of substitution
$$y(x)=x^r\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}$$
we substitute y(x) into the equation
$$ 3x^2{\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(n+r+1)(n+r+2)}a_{n+2}x^{n+r}} - x{\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+r+1)a_{n+1}x^{n+r}}+{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}} = 0$$
then
$$ 3{\sum_{n=2}^\infty {(n+r-1)(n+r)}a_{n}x^{n+r}} - {\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+r)a_{n}x^{n+r}}+{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}} = 0$$
which gives us the relationship:
$$(3(n+r-1)(n+r)-(n+r)+1)a_n = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n\ge2$$
$$(-(n+r)+1)a_n = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n=1$$
$$a_n = 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n=0$$

For all n a is zero. I don't know where I'm making a mistake, there should be a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a mistake in the equation $F(r) = \cdots$. The last term should be $+\frac{1}{3}$, not $-\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ODE does not require the method of Frobenius. Notice that the degree of the monomial coefficient matches the order of the derivative it is attached to. This means we will have two monomial homogeneous solutions of the form $y=x^r$:

$$y = x^r \implies (3r^2-4r+1)x^r = (3r-1)(r-1)x^r = 0$$

therefore

$$y = C_1 x^{\frac{1}{3}}+C_2x$$

Comment: Ah yes I should have mentioned that this is homework of mine for a class and they wanted this to be solved with the frobenius method

Comment: @TheTechnomancer fair enough - once you fix your minor sign error you'll find that the recurrence relation terminates and is $0$.